# Difference between airbrake notifier.js vs airbrake-js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, airbrake

Does anyone know the difference between airbrake's notifier.js vs the new airbrake-js https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-js library?

Do we need to include both if i want to use airbrake-js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reading the blog](https://airbrake.io/blog/product/airbrake-v3-0) and the repo documentation, I assume that `airbrake-js` is the new "standard" JavaScript notifier for Airbrake.

Comment: Yes, i tried it out. Looks like we do not need the notifier.js if we use airbrake-js